# Question about document.querySelector multiple elements

Tags: queryselector

This works with one element but not multiple elements (such as `#container p, #container h2`):

```html
<button id="small" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">-</button>
<button id="big" type="button" onclick="changeFontSize(this)">+</button>

<script>function changeFontSize(target) {
  var demo = document.querySelector('#container p','#container h2');
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle
    ? getComputedStyle(demo)
    : demo.currentStyle;
  var fontSize;

  if (computedStyle) {
    fontSize = parseFloat(computedStyle && computedStyle.fontSize);

    if (target == document.getElementById("big")) {
      fontSize += 1;
    } else if (target == document.getElementById("small")) {
      fontSize -= 1;
    }
    demo.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `querySelector` can only select one element at a time.

Comment: I tried querySelectorAll and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of `querySelectAll` the correct syntax is as follows:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#container').querySelectorAll('p, h2');

for(const dom of demo) {

  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle
    ? getComputedStyle(dom)
    : demo.currentStyle;

  let fontSize;

  if (computedStyle) {

    fontSize = parseFloat(computedStyle && computedStyle.fontSize);

    if (target == document.getElementById("big")) {

     fontSize += 1;

    } else if (target == document.getElementById("small")) {

     fontSize -= 1;

    }

    dom.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  }

}
```

---

**Alternative**

On a separate note, if you really want to manipulate the font size of an entire site via a user adjustable setting then consider setting a font size on the `<body>` tag and then using `rem` (root em) for style font sizing on everything else.

```js
document.querySelector('html').style.fontSize = '12px';

window.fontSize = function (step) {

  const dom = document.querySelector('html')

  const size = parseInt(dom.style.fontSize);

  dom.style.fontSize = (size + step) + 'px'

}
```

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 4rem;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p.caption {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div>

    <button onClick="fontSize(-1)">Decrease</button>

    <button onClick="fontSize(1)">Increase</button>

  </div>

  <h1>Heading 1</h1>

  <h2>Heading 2</h2>

  <p>Paragraph</p>

  <p class="caption">A tiny caption</p>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfect. Thanks you very much  :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

You can either select one by one using `document.querySelector` and assign to different variable

```js
var v1 = document.querySelector('#container p');
var v2 = document.querySelector('#container h2');
```

#### Option 2

You can assign unique id to each element then select using querySelector and assign to different variable

```js
var v1 = document.querySelector('#first_element');
var v2 = document.querySelector('#second_element');
```

#### Option 3

You can assign class to elements you want to select and then use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements with that class

```js
var v1 = document.querySelectorAll('.all_elements');
```

**Note:** `querySelector` return single element and `querySelectorAll` return multiple elements so you need to handle them accordingly

Comment: Option One would have worked best but it did not work when I tried it :(

Comment: @bryanaps please share you html you have created